# In Gdalinfo what does Block: 1000x1 means and differ from 1000x2?

Tags: gdalinfo

I am doing some work on 1k elevation raster tiles and I noticed that after some processing, Gdalinfo shows block:1000x2 while the original tiles show 1000x1.

What do the x1 and x2 mean in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block size 1000x1 means that the original TIFF is organized so that data was written row by row (1 row with 1000 pixels) while now the TIFF has strips which contain two rows. Nothing to be worried. For bigger images it is usually better to have tiled than striped TIFFs (-co TILED=YES).

1x and 2x mean the same as RowsPerStrip in the TIFF standard https://www.itu.int/itudoc/itu-t/com16/tiff-fx/docs/tiff6.pdf.

> **RowsPerStrip**
>
> Tag = 278 (116.H)
>
> Type = SHORT or LONG
>
> The number of rows in each
> strip (except possibly the last strip.) For example, if ImageLength is
> 24, and RowsPerStrip is 10, then there are 3 strips, with 10 rows in
> the first strip, 10 rows in the second strip, and 4 rows in the third
> strip. (The data in the last strip is not padded with 6 extra rows of
> dummy data.

Comment: Thank you! FME actually shows it as RowsPerStrip too. It makes sense now